# Upload two different files in the same form

Tags: php, html

The issue here is, when I Upload videos, it works perfectly but not images which is giving me a hard time to figure out what the error may be

---

### This is what the HTML looks like:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
   <h1>Browse for file to upload:</h1>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="file"><h1><b>Select Video</b></h1></label>
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload1[]" id="fileToUpload" >

    <br><br>

    <label for="file"><h2><b>Select Image</b></h2></label>
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload1[]" id="fileToUpload" >
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>
```

**The PHP Script looks like this:**

```
$error = null;
$success = null;
$info = [];
$uploadOk = 1;


$allowedMimes = ['video/mp4', 'image/jpg'];

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $counter = 0;
    foreach ( $_FILES['fileToUpload1']['name'] as $file ):
        $target_file = UPLOAD_DIR . basename($file);
        if ( in_array(mime_content_type($_FILES['fileToUpload1']["tmp_name"][$counter]), $allowedMimes) ){
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload1']["tmp_name"][$counter], $target_file)) {
                $info[] = "File ".++$counter."($file) uploaded successfully";
            }else {
                $info[] = "File ".++$counter."($file) cannot be uploaded";
            }
        } else {
            $info[] = "File ".++$counter. " is not allowed.";
        }

    endforeach;    
} else {
    echo "upload a file.";
}


?>


    <ul>
    <?php foreach($info as $i){ ?>
    <li><?=$i;?></li>
    <?php }?>
</ul>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: When you upload **two** *video* files this code works as you expected? it doesn't sound right...

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @Dekelyeah, when I upload two videos it works, but what I want is one video and one image to be uploaded.

Comment: @Max P not an error, but it echo "file cannot be uploaded", which means its not processing other formats apart from the video format

Comment: what images are you trying to upload? and which browser you are using?

Comment: @Dekel its a jpg file and I use google chrome

Comment: Check the answer, I think it gives you a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mimetype of `jpg` files is actually `image/jpeg` (and not `iamge/jpg`), so if you are trying to upload `jpg` files you should change your `$allowedMimes` variable to:

```
$allowedMimes = ['video/mp4', 'image/jpeg'];
```

Also - if you want to support other image types you can use:

```
$allowedMimes = ['video/mp4', 'image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/bmp'];
```

Another option - if you want to support **all** image/audio/video types you can check only the first part of the string:

```
$allowedTypes = ['video', 'image', 'audio'];
...
if ( in_array(
    array_shift(
        explode("/", 
            mime_content_type($_FILES['fileToUpload1']["tmp_name"][$counter])
        )
    ),
    $allowedTypes) )
```

If you are using php>=5.4 you can use:

```
$allowedTypes = ['video', 'image', 'audio'];
...
if ( in_array(
    explode("/", 
        mime_content_type($_FILES['fileToUpload1']["tmp_name"][$counter])
    )[0],
    $allowedTypes) )
```

Comment: it still has the same issue, it accepts videos but not images

Comment: Which of the two you use? And what is the actual mime-type that you get for the image that you upload?

Comment: I used the one that supports all image/audio/video types and the error I got is Fatal error: Call to undefined function explde() in C:\wamp\www\upload\templated-visualize\index.php on line 31

Comment: yes, it should be `explode`. typo... fixed in my answer.

Comment: Did you change the typo?

Comment: but when I use the one that supports all image/audio/video types it displays Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\wamp\www\upload\upload.php on line 34 but it still works.